# BeautifulSoup find() does not match existing text

Tags: html, parsing, beautifulsoup

With BeautifulSoup I try to find a `<th>text</th>`-Tag with a regular expression.
But the regular expression does not match the confirmed text.

```py
soup.find('th', text=re.compile("test"))
```

A testcase to see the output **black horse**:

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>brown dog</th>
      <th><a href="#">white cat</a></th>
      <th>black <a href="#">horse</a></th>
   </tr>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

headers = soup.find_all('th')
for header in headers:
    print(header.text)
```

Output:

```
brown dog
white cat
black horse
```

This confirmes, there is a text with content **black horse**.

But if I try to find it with a regular expression, there is no match:

```py
for col in [ 'dog', 'cat', 'horse' ]:
    print( soup.find('th', text=re.compile(col)) )
```

Output:

```
<th>brown dog</th>
<th><a href="#">white cat</a></th>
None
```

The third line is **None** but should be `<th>black <a href="#">horse</a></th>` like the others, including the link.
Why does it not match?

I see lots of similar questions on stackoverflow, but can't find this case.

BS-version is:

```
import bs4
print ("BeautifulSoup %6.6s" % bs4.__version__)
BeautifulSoup  4.8.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I am getting the same output using regex.However since you have `BS 4.8.2` you can try following **css** selector.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>brown dog</th>
      <th><a href="#">white cat</a></th>
      <th>black <a href="#">horse</a></th>
   </tr>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for col in [ 'dog', 'cat', 'horse' ]:
    print(soup.select_one('th:contains("{}")'.format(col)))
```

**Output**:

```
<th>brown dog</th>
<th><a href="#">white cat</a></th>
<th>black <a href="#">horse</a></th>
```

Comment: You're right, the css selector is working. But ist this a BeautifulSoup-Bug?

Comment: Yes,I think so its definitely Bug.